# AngularJS bind multiple dropdowns to one value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

There are 3 drop downs and all are bound to one module. Here is my fiddle

[jsfiddle.net/deborad/7sv0y153/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/deborad/7sv0y153/2/)

. All models are set to `myOption` . When one of them is selected, the value of each drop down is printed. It is ok. But the rest of drop downs' selected values become empty.
 I want to make other 2 drop values to `Select` when one drop down is selected. Any solution ?

Comment: do you mean that you want when one of the selects goes to its initial state - "Select" is selected then other two should go to that state as well ?

Comment: @shershen. Thanks for your attention. Assume the second drop down is selected and set the value to 'AAA' , then 1st and 3rd drop downs values are required to be value 'Select'. (Here the problem is, 1st and 3rd values become empty !!!)

Comment: If what me and @shershen understood is correct, then you can achieve it by having an object
`var obj =  { label: 'Select', value: '0' };` and use it in your options like this in all options `$scope.options = [ obj, {..},{..}] `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed your JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/7sv0y153/4/

You shouldn't include the default empty option in your ng-options array, but have it as follows in each "select" element:

`<option value="">Select</option>`

This way, the "select" element will treat the option with the empty value as a default if it doesn't find a match in its ng-options.

Hope this helps.